# How to split a large shared component library

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I have a shared library built using vue-cli (Vue v2) with webpack 4.
The problem is the library is getting bigger and bigger (it already weighs 3MB).

The way I'm exposing the components today is through a main.js file that looks like this:

```js
export { default as AqTableActions } from '@/components/table/AqTableActions.vue';
export { default as AqEmptyPage } from '@/components/AqEmptyPage.vue';
export { default as AqErrorPage } from '@/components/AqErrorPage.vue';
```

To build it I run this:

```sh
vue-cli-service build --target lib src/main.js
```

And then I use it like this:

```js
import { AqEmptyPage, AqTableActions } from '@aqua/shared';
```

How can I reduce the bundle size?

Comment: If your shared lib is bundled, it will be difficult to the user to split it, you should "compile" each vue component into a single file, checkout what vue-material does https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/4de86085fd9ef835df2caf534249bc7f6c21f5f4/build/lib/webpack.js#L40

Comment: https://blog.theodo.com/2021/04/library-tree-shaking/